# How to solved error with validation when enabling button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following problem with a validation that I perform which requests that when selecting the files in which the input file Upload Files button is enabled, the problem that I am presenting is that when trying to upload the second file, the button is enabled without having uploaded the first.

But if you select the files in order starting with the first, you will not be enabled until you load the second file.

The code I used for this validation is the following:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("FileOneToUpload");
var input = document.getElementById("FileTwoToUpload");

input.addEventListener('change', check);

function check(event) {
  var validate = this.files.length == 0 ? true : false;
  var send = document.getElementById("upload");
  send.disabled = validate;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File 1:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="file" name="OneToUpload" id="FileOneToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File 2:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="file" name="TwoToUpload" id="FileTwoToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">Upload Files</button>
</div>
```

Is there something additional that I must correct in validation or is there another way that I can do it but that meets this criteria?

**Update 1:**

I have tried with one of the answers they give me but I still do not get a result, I have separated the two input variables and I have assigned them to each of the Listener events but it still does not work, I add the code that I have made based on one of the answers.

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("FileOneToUpload"); 
var input2 = document.getElementById("FileTwoToUpload");

input1.addEventListener('change', check); 
input2.addEventListener('change', check); 

function check(event) { 
    var validate = this.files.length == 0 ? true : false;   
    var send = document.getElementById("upload"); 
    send.disabled = validate;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File 1:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="OneToUpload" id="FileOneToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required="">
              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="pdfToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File 2:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="file" name="TwoToUpload" id="FileTwoToUpload" class="btn" accept=".pdf" required="">
              </div>
                    </div>
          
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" disabled="">Upload Files</button>
          </div>
```

Possibly I have not explained enough, what I require is that the upload files button is enabled but only until you have selected files in `File 1` and `File 2`, that is to say that when the files are already selected in each of the inputs the button is enabled to proceed with the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding `input` var, so no event listener will get attached to the first one.

```
var input = document.getElementById("FileOneToUpload");
var input = document.getElementById("FileTwoToUpload");
```

Save two different input vars:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("FileOneToUpload");
var input2 = document.getElementById("FileTwoToUpload");

input1.addEventListener('change', check);
input2.addEventListener('change', check);

function check(event) {
  var validate = this.files.length == 0 ? true : false;
  var send = document.getElementById("upload");
  send.disabled = validate;
}
```

Also, you can simplify without ternary:

```
function check(event) {
      var validate = this.files.length == 0;
      var send = document.getElementById("upload");
      send.disabled = validate;
}
```

Or really even just

```
send.disabled = this.files.length == 0;
```

Comment: I have added a new update based on your recent response, where you indicate that I separately assign the variables, but I do not work, is there something additional that I need to correct in my code ?